# Is it correct command to create foreign key with index creation also? I got ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

Tags: oracle, indexing, foreign-keys, syntax-error, sqlplus

Is it correct or not?

```
alter table test
add constraint test_fk foreign key (prim_id)
references prim (prim_id)
using index 
(create index i_test_prim_fk 
on test(prim_id) tablespace index01)
on delete cascade
/
```

maybe using index not allowed here?

**using index
*
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option**

tried create fk expected error

Comment: A foreign key is a rule, not an index. It requires a pre-existing PK/UK index on the *parent* table, but not the child. An index on the child has nothing to do with the FK's work. However, it is often a good idea to *additionally* index the constrained child column for performace reasons related to updates or deletes on the parent table. This is often called "a foreign key index" and is recommended practice, but is not actually part of the FK. That's why the FK DDL doesn't have a concept of `using index` like PK/UK constraints do.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check is to read the documentation.

`ALTER TABLE` has [the syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877):

> [image: ALTER TABLE syntax diagram]

> #### `constraint_clauses::=`
>
> [image: constraint clauses syntax diagram]

> #### `out_of_line_ref_constraint::=`
>
> [image: Out-of-line referential constraint syntax diagram]
>
> #### `references_clause::=`
>
> [image: References clause syntax diagram]
>
> #### `constraint_state::=`
>
> [image: Constraint state syntax diagram]
>
> #### `using_index::=`
>
> [image: Using index clause syntax diagram]

and then the `CREATE INDEX` syntax is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-INDEX.html#GUID-1F89BBC0-825F-4215-AF71-7588E31D8BFE__I2125762).

The `using_index` clause specifies the following restrictions:

> #### `using_index_clause`
>
> You can specify the `using_index_clause` only when enabling unique or primary key constraints. You can specify the clauses of the `using_index_clause` in any order, but you can specify each clause only once.
>
> If you specify `schema.index`, then Oracle attempts to enforce the constraint using the specified index. If Oracle cannot find the index or cannot use the index to enforce the constraint, then Oracle returns an error.
>
> If you specify the `create_index_statement`, then Oracle attempts to create the index and use it to enforce the constraint. If Oracle cannot create the index or cannot use the index to enforce the constraint, then Oracle returns an error.
>
> If you neither specify an existing index nor create a new index, then Oracle creates the index. In this case:
>
> - The index receives the same name as the constraint.
> - If table is partitioned, then you can specify a locally or globally partitioned index for the unique or primary key constraint.
>
> #### Restrictions on the `using_index_clause`
>
> The following restrictions apply to the using_index_clause:
>
> - You cannot specify this clause for a view constraint.
> - You cannot specify this clause for a NOT NULL, foreign key, or check constraint.
> - You cannot specify an index (`schema.index`) or create an index (`create_index_statement`) when enabling the primary key of an index-organized table.
> - You cannot specify the `parallel_clause` of `index_attributes`.
> - The `INDEXTYPE IS ...` clause of `index_properties` is not valid in the definition of a constraint.

No, your statement is not valid as:

1. The `ON DELETE CASCADE` should be before `USING INDEX`.
2. `USING INDEX` should create a unique or primary key index.
3. The unique index should be on `prim` and not `test`.

You can use two statements:

```sql
ALTER TABLE prim
  ADD CONSTRAINT pk__prim__prim_id
    PRIMARY KEY (prim_id)
    USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i__prim__prim_id__u ON prim(prim_id))
/

alter table test
  add constraint test_fk
      foreign key (prim_id)
      references prim (prim_id)
      on delete cascade
/
```

Comment: What the OP probably wants, is to add a non-unique index on the foreign key column in `test`.

Comment: Thanx, so Copilot AI was wrong.